# getting value from table in another controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to load model from another controller and with associated tables .

I have make this line to make that but the second line have something wrong with it .

```
 $transactions = TableRegistry::get('Transactions')->find()->all();
      $this->$transactions = [
        'contain' => ['TransactionsTypes.BudgetItems', 'Contractors', 'Purposes', 'TrustOrders', 'Contracts']
    ];
```

So how can i contains the tables TransactionsTypes.BudgetItems , .... to my  function at the controller in cakephp3

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$transactions=$this->loadModel ( 'Transactions' );
$transactions->find('all',['contain'=>['TransactionsTypes.BudgetItems', 'Contractors', 'Purposes', 'TrustOrders', 'Contracts']])->toAray();
```

Comment: It's giving me error 
TransactionsTypes is not associated with TransactionsTypes 
But it's have relationship with it at its model .

Comment: Look likes something wrong, 
have you used $transactions=$this->loadModel ( 'TransactionsTypes' );
instead
$transactions=$this->loadModel ( 'Transactions' );

Comment: It's gives me that :TransactionsTypes is not associated with TransactionsTypes

Answer (score 0):

With your code, you are setting `$transactions` to be the result of finding all records without any associations, and then setting `$this->transactions` to be a simple array. @ashanrupasinghe's answer is one alternative, here is another:

```
$transactions = TableRegistry::get('Transactions')->find()->all()
    ->contain(['TransactionsTypes.BudgetItems', 'Contractors', 'Purposes', 'TrustOrders', 'Contracts']);
```